# SQL complicated query

Tags: sql, select

I have a following problem with my SQL query. I was managed to successfully execute about 15 of them but this one makes me sick. It's even hard to translate but probably you will understand.

Show years and months numbers and their sum of  costs of ‘borrowed-time’ in those months where monthly sum of costs was lesser then the biggest one in February and March in 2006.

And this is what I have so far (one of the version of the query because I tried many of them)

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATA_WYP), SUM(KOSZT) 
FROM WYPOZYCZENIA 
WHERE KOSZT<(SELECT SUM(KOSZT)  
             FROM WYPOZYCZENIA 
             WHERE SUM(KOSZT)<(SELECT MAX(SUM(KOSZT)) 
                               FROM WYPOZYCZENIA 
                               WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATA_WYP)='2' OR 
                               EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATA_WYP)='3' 
                               GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATA_WYP)))
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATA_WYP);
```

The problem is that I cannot equal `SUM(KOSZT)`, tried to save them using `AS` but it doesn't work either.

Please help me because it already ruined my day.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if this is my sql using having to compare the grouped by items (sums etc)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

To filter by the results of an aggregate function in a SQL query, place the comparisons in a `HAVING` statement.

Comment: +1; but don't let Joe Celko see your rant; for some reason he believes the exact opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming Oracle or DB2 because of the keywords in your sample query.

Using a CTE to find the max for the 2 months and using `HAVING` for the condition simplifies the expression somewhat, this should (more or less) do what you need;

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT SUM(KOSZT) mx FROM WYPOZYCZENIA
  WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATA_WYP) IN ('2','3')
    AND EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM DATA_WYP) = '2006'
  GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATA_WYP)
)
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATA_WYP) Year, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATA_WYP) Month,
       SUM(KOSZT) KOSZT
FROM WYPOZYCZENIA 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(Year FROM DATA_WYP), EXTRACT(Month FROM DATA_WYP)
HAVING SUM(KOSZT) < (SELECT MAX(mx) FROM cte)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79519/2).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT YEAR(data_wyp) year,
       MONTH(data_wyp) month,
       SUM(koszt) koszt
  FROM wypozyczenia 
 GROUP BY year, month
HAVING koszt <  (SELECT SUM(koszt) koszt 
                       FROM wypozyczenia 
                      WHERE MONTH(data_wyp) IN (2, 3) 
                        AND YEAR(data_wyp) = 2006
                      GROUP BY MONTH(data_wyp)
                      ORDER BY koszt DESC LIMIT 1)
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a42e/14)** (MySql)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out-:

**SELECT**  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATA_WYP) 
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATA_WYP),
        SUM(KOSZT) 
**FROM** WYPOZYCZENIA 
**GROUP BY** EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATA_WYP)
          EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATA_WYP) 
**HAVING** Sum(KOSZT)<(**SELECT** MAX(SUM(KOSZT)) 
             **FROM**  WYPOZYCZENIA 
                                           **WHERE** EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATA_WYP)=2006

              EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATA_WYP) IN ('2','3')
                                           **GROUP BY** EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATA_WYP))

I hope this solves your problem.